# Make responsive bootstrap table horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

I have a bootstrap table like

```
 <table class="table-responsive" >
    <th> Points </th>                                           
    <th> Players </th>                               
    <th> Prizes </th>

    <tr>
      <td>{{ points }}</td>              
      <td>{{ players }}</td>              
      <td>{{ prizes }}</td>                            
    </tr>

 </table>
```

and this table looks like

[image]

The problem is that it looks like this , even in small screens. How can I make it horizontal in small screens, like the following image ?

[image]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/emtrdc50/

Comment: @RahulChandrasekharan Cheat of the century ! A really nice and simple solution that did not cross my mind. Nice work. Thanks

Comment: @RahulChandrasekharan Please make this an answer if you will, so I can upvote and pick this as a right answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired structure of table on small screen could not be achieved using the original table as the structure is different. So a hack of displaying an alternate table on the smaller screens and hiding the original table on the smaller screen and vice versa would be functional.

### HTML

```
<table id="big-screen">
    <tr>
        <th>Points</th>                                           
        <th>Players</th>                               
        <th>Prizes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ points }}</td>              
        <td>{{ players }}</td>              
        <td>{{ prizes }}</td>                            
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="small-screen">
    <tr><th>Points</th></tr>
    <tr><td>{{ points }}</td></tr>                               
    <tr><th>Players</th></tr>
    <tr><td>{{ players }}</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Prizes</th></tr>
    <tr><td>{{ prizes }}</td></tr>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 319px) {
  #small-screen {
    display: table;
  }
  #big-screen {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  #small-screen {
    display: none;
  }
  #big-screen {
    display: table;
  }
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emtrdc50/1/)